# iOS Authorize.net integration issue

Tags: iphone, ios, authorize.net

I am developing iOS app, in which I have integrated authorize.net payment gateways using auth.net iOS API.
I followed each and every steps which are mentioned in their doc. Now each time, when a transaction request is sent to auth.net server on live environment it gives me error (Code E00007) i.e. "User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values".
I checked Login ID and Transaction Key and those are correct.
Even I tried with Auth.net support person, but still it did not work out.
The test enviroment and request were successful. But on Live env. it gives me the problem

My code follows:
For device registration:
Here I have put XXXX.... instead of real transaction key and login id.

```
MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest *mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest =
[MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest];
mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest.mobileDevice.mobileDeviceId =
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"_"];
mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest.mobileDevice.mobileDescription = @"iPhone";
mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name = @"XXXXXXXXX";
mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.password = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

[AuthNet authNetWithEnvironment:ENV_LIVE];
AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];
[an mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest:mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest];
```

After that the code for payment request:

```
    MobileDeviceLoginRequest *mobileDeviceLoginRequest = [MobileDeviceLoginRequest mobileDeviceLoginRequest];
    mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name = @"XXXXX";
    mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.password = @"XXXXXX";
    mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.mobileDeviceId =
    [[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"_"];

    // Set up an AuthNet instance.
    [AuthNet authNetWithEnvironment:ENV_LIVE];

    AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];
    [an setDelegate:self];

    // Process a mobile device login request.
    [an mobileDeviceLoginRequest:mobileDeviceLoginRequest];
```

But in the initial registering request I am receiving the failure with error code E00007. Any settings I missed?

Comment: What do you use in the place of username and password either original username and password or anyother api  key in place of password .Is it secure when we use the original password in xcode?

Answer (score 1):

please provide the transaction key

```
mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.transactionKey = @"XXXXXX";
```

it works for me

Comment: That seems like exactly the sort of data that we shouldn't encourage people to post publicly!

Comment: How to get TransactionKey?

Comment: @MohammadArsalan Where we have to add App Login ID? and it what we have to enter in Name and Password? Because merchant will not give password to developer!!